# Xamarin Android - Handling StringBuilders

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, stringbuilder, allocation

I am using a string builder to more effectively handle my information(by choice), where on option switched on it appends it to the list.
Im doing this every second(at minimum), and im wondering, is it better to use `StringBuilder.Clear();` or `StringBuilder.Lenght = 0;`

I am not sure which of these two has a better memory management, and im hoping someone here knows. Or is there even a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`Clear()` was introduced later (since 4.0) than `Length`. That's the main difference. If you don't consider to support a lower .NET version, go for `Clear()`. Performancewise `Length = 0` should be faster, because `Clear()` calls it intern, but it also should make no big difference, especially if you call it only once per second. Avoid [Premature Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). I would go for `Clear()`, because it is more readable and only use `Length = 0` in a performance critical scenario, where I ran out of other options.

This is the source implementation of Microsoft:

```
// Convenience method for sb.Length=0;
public StringBuilder Clear() {
    this.Length = 0;
    return this;
}
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs

Mono is using the same implementation.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs

Comment: Thanks for the info!
As for which to use, i will use Lenght = 0 instead, since i need as much performance as possible, considering my app is running a bunch of data fetching and calculations(and if checks) each update interval, and now  that i added this function that includes stringbuilder, it might tripple in performance overhead.